# Discord.py Send a specified, by the discord user, message to a channel

Tags: python, discord.py, tuples

Is it possible to get the user's input and then return it? This is my concept:

```
@bot.command()
async def return(ctx, *msg):
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

let's say that the user types: `!return Some message specified by the user`

but this returns: `('Some', 'message', 'specified', 'by', 'the', 'user')`

So, is it possible to make it return: `Some message specified by the user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `*` separated with a comma to make this work:

```py
@bot.command()
async def return(ctx, *, msg):
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

Reference:
[Keyword only arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=keyword#keyword-only-arguments)

Comment: This actually worked. Thanks. But can you provide an explanation?

Comment: It's stated in the docs of discord.py, I edited my answer with a link to it @Tony